# How do I open my App's Settings when they don't exist

Tags: ios, swift, settings

My app requires access to the user's media library.  My question relates tho the following scenario:

1. No iOS Settings entry exists for this app.
2. The user presses link to launch Apple's Media Picker.
3. I pop up Apple's Media Library Access Authorization dialog           `MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization()`
4. The user presses 'Don't Allow'
5. The user again presses link to launch Apple's Media Picker.
6. I pop up an alert dialog explaining issue and providing button to open the app's iOS Settings.

   ```
   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
   ```

This works fine as long as the iOS Settings app/screen is not open. The iOS Settings app launches and opens my app's newly created settings.

If iOS Settings app/screen is open (*not to my app, just open somewhere*), the iOS Settings app appears and is positioned where ever it was.  Not what I want.
If I switch back to my app, pop up the dialog, and do the open URL a second time, the iOS setting are opened for my app.

Is this normal behavior? How do I correct it?

Stackoverflow does a good job of presenting links to existing questions that may be the answer I'm looking for, but no go.

---

I am still stymied by my app settings issue. Further testing has brought to lite a related issue. Like the settings, my app icon does not appear. Both problems appear to be resolved by a 2nd installation. I thought that by providing details on the app icon, someone might see the problem.

Mac Mini
Mojave 10.14.4
Xcode 10.2
Xcode - Project - IOS Deployment Target = 11.0
Xcode - Target - Deployment Targets = 12.1
Xcode - Swift v5

Physical devices:
    - iPhone 6plus ios 12.1.3
    - iPhone X iOS 12.1.4

**Behavior:**

```
- installation on Xcode Simulator results in:
    * icon appears as it should with initial installation.(multiple devices tested)  

- installation on physical devices by Xcode side-loading via debugger results in:
    * after initial installation, icon is missing. 
    * app runs as expected.
    * ios settings entry exists.
    * ios iPhone storage entry exists.
    * 2nd debug run, icon appears. (2nd run can be immediate or after device disconnected/reconnected or Xcode restarted)  

- installation of ipa on physical devices by Xcode -> Window -> Devices & Simulators results in:
    * after initial installation, icon is missing.
    * (of course app cannot be run without icon)
    * ios settings entry exists.
    * ios iPhone storage entry exists.
    * 2nd ipa installation, icon appears. (2nd run can be immediate or after device disconnected/reconnected or Xcode restarted)
```

**Note:** I have recreated and re-generated my icons by several different tools. No change in behavior.

**Note:** I have downloaded a couple of simple technology demonstration Xcode projects from GitHub.
They do not contain any icons. They rely on the ios default icon. Same behavior as my app.

Any insights or outright guesses would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using pretty much the same code to open settings in my app but on my end it opens my apps settings page just fine, even when settings is already open. My code is a little bit different: `UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)` This is probably because I'm using a newer version of Swift. You could try to set up a fresh project with the latest version of Xcode and iOS and try to reproduce the issue. If the issue is gone, you should update everything to the latest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Zandor.  My Swift 4.0 IOS 12.1 code was using your suggested open URL syntax.  I just had a brain fart.  I went ahead and upgraded the project to Swift 4.2 as you suggested.  I still get the same behavior when testing on a physical iPhone 6 plus or an iPhone X, both tethered and untethered.  So....no joy.

Comment: I just created a new project, put a button in the center of the storyboard view, made an action outlet and put my earlier line in the action. I noticed that it would open settings but not my app page. This was because the app page wasn't there when manually scrolling through settings. Then I enabled background mode remote notifications and the page showed up. Now clicking the button opens the app's settings. Your app might not have any settings in there? You can download my test project at https://git.zsinfo.nl/Zandor300/appsettingstest to try it yourself. **(Xcode 12.2, Swift 5)**

Comment: Zandor, thanks for your efforts.  In my situation, the System Settings app entry appears to be created when the app is installed/side-loaded/run by Xcode. (I would like to test installing on a physical device without running....can that be done in Xcode?)

Comment: What I said in my last comment was incorrect.  The System's Settings app entry appears to be created when I allow or disallow Music Library Access Authorization.

Comment: You can just run on your device and cancel before the app gets started but has installed. Otherwise, you could try to compile to an ipa file by archiving and exporting through your organizer and then through your device manager, install the ipa on your device. https://docs.monaca.io/en/products_guide/monaca_ide/deploy/non_market_deploy/#install-using-xcode

Comment: My concern is that IF i distribute the app on the app store, a user will experience the issue and become confused.  Although installing the ipa on my device would be interesting, would it duplicate an app store install?

Comment: Ok.  Remember I'm a noob.  I created and exported an archive choosing "Development" distribution method. I then deployed on an iPhone 6 plus per the link in your comment.  No errors, but the app icon did not appear.  If I reboot the phone, the app icon appears.  I could launch the app and did NOT experience my Settings issue….App Settings opened as desired.  Earlier, when I was testing in Xcode debugger using the iPhone 6 plus, I experienced similar behavior but the app began running, so I ignored it.  A 2nd deployment caused the app icon to appear.  Is this normal?  Are the issues related?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth..... I submitted the app to Apple for review.  It was approved and is on the app store (Song Announcer).   The ipa that I uploaded to App Store Connect exhibited the same "no app icon when initially installed" behavior when installed on my devices via Xcode.   When downloaded from the App Store, the icon appears as expected.

Go figure.

Comment: This should be a comment. Answers need to have sufficient information to understand the answer. The answer should be described in a reasonable level of detail and / or include a minimal example of the answer.

Comment: The answer is "don't worry about it".  In my case it appears to be an Xcode only issue whether side-loading or deploying ipa to device.